# Will accordion with pure html checkbox pass accessibility

Tags: html, accessibility, accordion

sample here

```
<!--http://codepen.io/CesarGabriel/pen/tLDwH-->

            <div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="check-1" />
            <label for="check-1">Option 1</label>
            <article>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A, odit, quia hic ipsam laboriosam dignissimos suscipit eligendi! Aspernatur, ad, suscipit officiis repellat consequuntur quod quibusdam sint nobis magnam voluptates veritatis?</p>
            </article>
        </div>
```

and css

```
input:checked ~ article {
    border-bottom-left-radius: .25em;
    border-bottom-right-radius: .25em;
    height: auto;
    margin-bottom: .125em;
}
```

it is missing 'tabindex' for sure

other than that is this set friendly for accessibility?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you already consulted the [WAI-ARIA Authoring Practices](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#accordion)? It has a section for the accordion.  If you're going to have sections that expand and collapse (which is typically what an accordion does), you'll need to track aria-expanded=true/false.  And you'll need role=tablist for the headers and role=tabpanel for the contents.  And handle keyboard navigation, of course.

Comment: Nice demo here http://heydonworks.com/practical_aria_examples/#progressive-collapsibles

Comment: thanks for the info, slugolicious and Ted, so i will need javascript for <aria-expanded=true/false> section?